# Extracting types from object properties when they are functions

Tags: typescript, types, interface

Hello I am trying to extract the properties of an object like this:

```js
const combinedReducers = {
    markers: markersReducer, // () => MarkType
    mapCenter: setMapCenter // () => CenterType
}
```

The problem is I don't want to do it individually per property. And second issue is that the properties are functions that return something, and I want the type of that.
It would be something like this

```js
interface Props {
    markers: MarkType,
    center: CenterType
}
```

Is this even possible? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do it:

```js
const markersReducer = () => 'hello'
const setMapCenter = () => 42

const combinedReducers = {
  markers: markersReducer, // () => MarkType
  mapCenter: setMapCenter // () => CenterType
}

type Fn = (...args: any) => any

type Props<Obj extends Record<string, Fn>> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: ReturnType<Obj[Prop]>
}

type Result = Props<typeof combinedReducers>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwE4GsCmSICU0BMCuwGMAvDABQCUpAfDAOQAWaANiyPQLABQoksENFACyCAA4BhNGCjEyVWjAAsAJh48%200GKDgAjAJZg8OAkUykYAbx4x4ydJgBcd1Bmx5CGADQwA9L4pqEjpRVAAVAE8xNBs7SWlZJGdBEXEpGWJ-QMV0xMjongBfdW4oKLQYADEwC3IAOgbkAHMIZwQwCKC6doiSsuiYAAUkEDEIAB4AeV0AKxg0AA9ZMFwIGBxQJFxx6CRDJp9qmjoya25bAG1h0ZhDGHQIkAAzGGmZgF1nHCh8JDB8tBTWZXEZid40Ip9crrNAQfAsWBka5jcb9NDPbQgPSGYweMwQGhAA)

[ReturnType docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype)